# Meaning of "abgefrühstückt"?

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context

In a mathematics video I'm watching on Youtube about probability, the tutor uses the sentence "wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung abgefrühstückt." I typed "abgefrühstückt" into a few different translators, but all of them are returning "breakfast" and "had breakfast," but I'm pretty sure the tutor isn't talking about breakfast. The DeepL translator has given me "probabilistic calculation breakfasted" as the UK English translation.

I have German subtitles on, and have double-checked the spelling. According to the subtitles, he is definitely saying "abgefrühstückt."

If it is helpful, this is the video and the sentence I'm referring to occurs at 0:51.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oO_nkQ13Lok

Could someone please give me a better translation? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[*abgefrühstückt*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abfruehstuecken) is a metaphorical slang equivalent for *erledigt*, meaning "finished", "done".

I speculate, it stems from the breakfast in hotels, when the breakfast buffet is *abgefrühstückt*, nothing of it is left any more.

Comment: Thank you. Usually translators like DeepL provide a second meaning (where there is one), but not this time. Your example certainly makes sense if it is used as analogy for something being used up or finished up.

Answer (score 3):

`etwas abfrühstücken` is a colloquial term for `etwas erledigen`, as you can see in [this Duden entry](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abfruehstuecken).
The provided example in this entry is

> das Thema ist längst abgefrühstückt

which translates to 'the topic is already done'. This is very similar to your tutor's

> Die Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung ist abgefrühstückt.

He wants to express that the topic `Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung`is done.

Answer (score 3):

There's no connection to mathematics. "Etwas ist abgefrühstückt" is just a colloquial way of saying something has been finished, something is dealt with, something is done. It often has a bit of a derogatory aspect, like one didn't put much time and/or effort in the task:

> Das Thema ist doch schon längst abgefrühstückt, warum fängt er jetzt wieder davon an?

> This topic has been dealt with long ago, why does he start with it again?

or

> Der Tabellenführer hat den Dorfclub total abgefrühstückt.

> The leader in the ranking gave the team from the sticks a total drubbing.

A probable origin might be in the care of large groups. If, for example, you have to feed a few hundred cattle every morning, you probably won't invest too much effort into each indivual cow ;) A similar occasion might occur in large, not very high-class hotels. The individuals get their meal, one after the next, without any special treatment for anybody.

Comment: I get what you mean. He says it in the middle of explaining a problem (rather than at the end), but he seems to be referring to a YouTube playlist of probability examples that he has already finished doing. So that would make sense.